# Confirmation of correct use of code to prevent SQL injection and correct use of the using statement

Tags: c#, mysql, database

```
else if(updated_password == confirm_password)
{
    old_user = textBox1.Text;
    old_pass = textBox2.Text;
    confirm_password = textBox4.Text;

    using (var old_connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=" + old_user + ";database=DB;password=" + old_pass))
    {
      old_connection.Open();

      string sql = "ALTER USER @user @'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY @newPass";
      MySqlCommand old_cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, old_connection);
      old_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", old_user);
      old_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@newPass", confirm_password);

      old_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

      MessageBox.Show("Password changed successfully.", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
   }
}
```

Can someone please inform me if I got the malicious SQL injection sorted out by using the .Parameters.Add.. correctly and also that I am using the using statement correctly?

Comment: @stickybit I have seen a lot of arguments to the contrary regarding that issue. Especially on the platform.

Comment: Storing passwords as plain text is as bad as any of the other horrors you are looking to avoid

Comment: @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp no passwords are stored in the db. All passwords are stored in a string then gets cleared once the session is over or the application closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are using a code that is safe from the point of view of Sql Injection. Parameters keep the malicious users away from getting a successful hack to your db.

The using statement is correctly used and will ensure a proper resource utilization against your database.

However there are two points that could be changed to have a better approach:

- First: Store your connection string in a configuration file and read
  it from there. There is no point in building the same string again
  and again. And I don't even start to talk about what happen if you
  need to change something in that connection. If you hard code it
  inside your program then you need to change in many places and
  redistribute your program
- Second: AddWithValue is well known to be *evil*. You can read about it
  in many places but I find [this article to be
  highlightning](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/). Instead
  use `old_cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value =
  old_user;`

Comment: AddWithValue is still not evil, it has some restrictions only

Comment: `AddWithValue` is not "_evil_" when used with MySQL; see https://mysqlconnector.net/overview/using-addwithvalue/

Comment: @BradleyGrainger (I respond to you but I should write to the author of the doc page) why should one use a well known problematic API when a less troublesome API exists? What if this hypothetical dev ever needs to port that code to another database? I prefer to use Add and forget about AddWithValue even for MySql. Do you think that I am loosing something in leveraging the MySql database performances? From the article is not clear if AddWithValue has some other advantage over Add.

Comment: @Steve thank you for being too helpful. I noticed you also commented to my first post which was a while back so thanks for also replying!

Comment: @Steve it's not a "well-known problematic API" amongst MySQL developers (which is why it keeps getting used in SO answers). It's a concise (and self-documenting) way to add a new parameter, and I see no good reason to avoid perfectly-good MySQL code because it may cause problems when used with SQL Server. IMO there are so many differences between different DB servers (particularly if you're writing raw SQL, too!) that trying to use the most generic ADO.NET code possible--in case you ever port, which is unlikely--is not worth the effort.